# PHP facebook sdk - not redirecting back after login on localhost

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, localhost

I'm implementing a login button where I retrieve user's data like name and email. The main issue that seems to be happening is that I get an object not found screen with the message "

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated" after I log in. I set the url in my facebook app to localhost/Event.php but after this large code is placed after the url it won't load. Is this simply because I'm running it on Local host instead of an actual server? Any help is much appreciated.

My code:

```
require( __DIR__.'/Facebook/autoload.php' );
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id'                => 'my id',
'app_secret'            => 'my secret',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // optional

try {
if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
} else {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
}
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
} else {
    // getting short-lived access token
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    // OAuth 2.0 client handler
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client-
>getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

    // setting default access token to be used in script
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
}

// redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    header('Location: ./');
}

// getting basic info about user
try {
    $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email');
    $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    session_destroy();
    // redirecting user back to app login page
    header("Location: ./");
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$name = $profile['first_name'];
$email = $profile['email'];
$eventid = $_GET['id'];
// printing $profile array on the screen which holds the basic info about user
$sql = "INSERT INTO attendees (email, eventid, name) VALUES ('$email', '$eventid', '$name')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
// replace your website URL same as added in the developers.facebook.com/apps e.g. if you used http instead of https and you used non-www version or www version of your website then you must add the same here
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/Events.php', $permissions);

}
```

Comment: Which server is giving you that message - Facebook's, or your own? I suspect the latter, so it would basically be a 404 because you specified a wrong URL somewhere.

Comment: It's definitely my own. I'll check through the add details to see if I put in a wrong url somewhere,